# Misplaced \noalign in row-wise revealed tabular in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to produce beamer slides with a table that is revealed row-wise, and a reminder shown under the table corresponding to the currently revealed row.

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Test}   

some text here

\bigbreak 
\pause 

now a table here:

\begin{center}
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        \onslide<2->{
        Column 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Headline column 2 \& 3} \tabularnewline
         & Column 2 & Column 3 \tabularnewline
        \midrule 
        }
        \onslide<2->{
        entry 1: from slide 2 & AA & BB \tabularnewline[1.0em]
        }
        \onslide<3->{
        entry 2: from slide 3 & CC & DD \tabularnewline[0.25em] 
        }
        \onslide<4->{   
        entry 3: from slide 4 & EE & FF \tabularnewline[0.25em] 
        }
        \onslide<5->{
        entry 4: from slide 5 & GG & HH
        }
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\only<2>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 1}
\only<3>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 2}
\only<4>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 3}
\only<5>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 4}
}   


\end{document}
```

A pdf is produced which looks like I want to look, however, I get a bunch of error messages like the following:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.47 }
```

From other questions I thought these could be fixed by `\tabularnewline`, however, that doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\tabularnewline` in `\onslide<5->` and put `\bottomrule` inside

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Test}   

some text here

\bigbreak 
\pause 

now a table here:

\begin{center}
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        \onslide<2->{
        Column 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Headline column 2  3} \tabularnewline
         & Column 2 & Column 3 \tabularnewline
        \midrule 
        }
        \onslide<2->{
        entry 1: from slide 2 & AA & BB \tabularnewline[1.0em]
        }
        \onslide<3->{
        entry 2: from slide 3 & CC & DD \tabularnewline[0.25em] 
        }
        \onslide<4->{   
        entry 3: from slide 4 & EE & FF \tabularnewline[0.25em] 
        }
        \onslide<5->{
        entry 4: from slide 5 & GG & HH\tabularnewline[0.25em] 
        \bottomrule}

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\only<2>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 1}
\only<3>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 2}
\only<4>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 3}
\only<5>{\alert{Reminder}: reminder for entry 4}
}   


\end{document}
```